# Bootstrap full width and height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What would be a proper way to create a 2 column (Sidebar - Main) full width page with Bootstrap. I found few examples but mostly for width.

My attempt was to simply override:

```
html, body {
  margin:  0px;
  width:   100%;
  height:  100%;
}

sidebar {
  width:   200px;
  height:  100%;
}
```

However this creates concern for smaller screens. What would be a proper way to implement 2 column page layout. I'm trying to put make a layout for my administration panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the Bootstrap [fluid grid](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)? It will create a 2 column flexible layout. You can then use Bootstrap responsive to make that collapse down in one column if you want to.

Code from the Bootstrap website to do it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span2">
     <!--Sidebar content-->
   </div>
   <div class="span10">
     <!--Body content-->
   </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3581/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the sidebar to 200 px, why not set it in percentage (20%). This way, even if the user zooms in/out of the page on smaller/bigger screens, the sidebar will always remain consistent.

Comment: What about if they make it really small? It's probably best to set a `min-width` at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

see here http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is use media queries.

Float the sidebar in large screens, but in small screens do not, just let it line up under your content.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that but I still have border issue : the border of .lefty and .content is above the footer, don't know why, I solved your problem, would you solve mine ; )

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
```

```
      <div class="row header">
      <div class="col-xs-12">col-xs-12</div>
      </div> <!-- End of header -->


      <div class="row content">
              <div class="col-xs-3 lefty">lefty</div>
              <div class="col-xs-9 content">content</div>
      </div> <!-- End of content -->

      <div class="row footer">
      <div class="col-xs-12">col-xs-12</div>
      </div> <!-- End of footer -->
```

CSS :

```
    html,body{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.full-height{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.header{
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 10%;
    color: white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.lefty{
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 80%;
    color: white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.content{
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 80%;
    color: white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.footer{
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 10%;
    color: white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Best,